# Engagement with short woman

Tags: sources-mekorot

I read many years ago a book or an article that claim that it if you have an option to marry short or tall woman with same qualities it is advised to marry the low woman. The reason that stands beyond is that the heart and brain in short women are closer than the tall ones. I'm looking for the source.
As far as I remember there is also a tale in the Gemara that a Tana or Amora leaned down and whispered to his wife. I think the reason was she did not hear so well. The conclusion is that she was short. I didn't find the source for it as well.
Can you help me find the sources for the both?

Comment: Nedarim 9:10 implies that some people felt the opposite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source for short woman is in [Tuvia Harofe](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobias_Cohn)'s book (fourth part, Olam Katan, chapter 2):
It says that the short people have small space between heart and brain. The short people are usually flattering and very perceptive.

> בספר "מעשה טוביה" לטוביה הרופא (בחלק רביעי עולם הקטן פרק שני) כתב בדרך שאלה ותשובה "מדוע קצרי הקומה רובן חנפים וטובי ההבנה? תשובה: בהיותם קצרי הקומה יש מעט ריוח בין הלב שהוא משכן הרוח החיוני לבין המוח שבו מורשי המחשבה ובנקל יתנשאו האדים למעלה אל המוח אשר בו נולדה המחשבה ועי"ז ימהר להבין. וכן להיפך כל ארוך שוטה מטעם הנזכר.

Thanks to Rabbi Mordechai Itzhak from Holon.

The other source is in the Gemara as @Joel K mentioned in his comment:

> [איתתך גוצא גחין ותלחוש לה](http://sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.59a.6)